# How can a process die in a way that Process.wait wouldn't notice?

Tags: ruby, process, signals

I have this ruby script to manage [que](https://github.com/chanks/que/) processes. que doesn't support multi-proccess, see discussion [here](https://github.com/chanks/que/issues/225)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

cluster_size = 2    
puts "starting Que cluster with #{cluster_size} workers"; STDOUT.flush

%w[INT TERM].each do |signal|
  trap(signal) do
    @pids.each{|pid| Process.kill(signal, pid) }
  end
end

@pids = []
cluster_size.to_i.times do |n|
  puts "Starting Que daemon #{n}"; STDOUT.flush
  @pids << Process.spawn("que --worker-count $MAX_THREADS")
end

Process.waitall

puts "Que cluster has shut down"; STDOUT.flush
```

The script has been working well for a couple months. The other day I found things in a state where the script was running, but both child processes were dead.

I experimented with trying to replicate this. I killed the children with various signals, had them raise exceptions. In all cases, the script knew the process died and itself died.

How could the child process have died without the parent script knowing?

Comment: Can you provide more complete code?

Comment: @GentryChen done!

Answer (score 3):

> How could the child process have died without the parent script
>   knowing?

My guess is that the child process turned into a zombie and missed by `Process.waitall`.  Did you check if the child processes are zombies when it happens?

The zombie: 
If you have zombie processes it means those zombies have not been waited for by their parent (check the `PPID` with `ps -l`). In the end you have three choices: Fix the parent process (make it wait); kill the parent; or get over it.

Could you check your list of signals and `trap` it?

You can list all Signal(s) available (below is on windows):

```
Signal.list
=> {"EXIT"=>0, "INT"=>2, "ILL"=>4, "ABRT"=>22, "FPE"=>8, "KILL"=>9, "SEGV"=>11, "TERM"=>15}
```

Could you try to `trap` it via e.g. `INT` (note: you can have one trap per Signal) (

```
Signal.trap('SEGV') { throw :sigsegv }

catch :sigsegv
    start_what_you_need
end
puts 'OMG! Got a SEGV!'
```

Since your question is a general one, it is hard to give you a specific answer.

Comment: thanks! I've updated my question with the complete code now, if that helps.

Comment: @JohnBachir thank you for the update, better now. Which `ruby` are you using? Do you use `rvm`?  Is there any reason why you are catching only `%w[INT TERM]` and not others?

Comment: Ruby 2.5.1 on Heroku. Those are the only two signals the heroku docs mention so I thought it was sufficient.wdyt?

Comment: @JohnBachir My line of thinking for the catching of `INT` (which is ^C) `TERM` is (Traps Kill).  What if your process gives you SEGV or different signal?  As for the `rvm` I remember seeing this post - https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4422#issuecomment-406348867.  Which to quote "RVM set some traps and then clear them with trap - EXIT HUP INT QUIT TERM. So it sets trap for signals EXIT HUP INT QUIT TERM and clears them every time you change directory!".  Now the question how is the Heroku Ruby 2.5.1 managed?

Comment: Thanks for all this info, it's useful. But I believe you are thinking about this backwards - catching more signals will handle more scenarios where the parent gets a signal and wants to shut down the children cleanly. My situation is the parent getting no signal but the children being gone for some reason.

Comment: @JohnBachir You are right.  You could simply catch also in the children.

Answer (score 2):

Zombies are not the only possible cause for this problem -- stopped children may not be reported for a variety of reasons.

The existence of a zombie typically means that the parent has not properly waited on them. The posted code looks OK, though, so unless there's a framework bug lurking somewhere I'd want to look beyond the zombie apocalypse to explain this problem.

In contrast to zombies, which can't be fully reaped because they have no accessible parent, **frozen processes** have an intact parent but have stopped responding for some reason (waiting for an external process or I/O operation, memory problems, long or infinite looping, slow database operations, etc.).

On some platforms, Ruby can add a flag requesting return of stopped children that haven't been reported, using the following syntax:

```
waitpid(pid, Process::WUNTRACED)
```

AFAIK `waitall` doesn't have a version that accepts flags, so you'd have to aggregate this yourself, or use `pid = -1` to wait for any child process (the default if you omit pid) or `pid = 0` to wait for any child with the same process groupID as the calling process.

See documentation [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Process.html).